# Diacritics in steam name

Tags: steam

Is it possible or even allowed to use [Diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) in steam names (Not the login Name, the Name which is displayed in the games)? Here is an example of diacritics.

> NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s
>   ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳
>   TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘
>   ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: I know [exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6530134) where you pulled that quote from.  But I'm going to say certain characters are probably not allowed, such as the extra "crazy" looking ones.

Comment: @TimmyJim I think ist the best example ;D

Comment: I've used some special characters in my steam name before; I imagine that yes, copy and pasting a name with Diacritic characters would work. I'm not sure how steam handles that "demon text" for displaying, but theoretically it should work.

Comment: I wouldn't really call Zalgo text "diacritics" in any real sense, to be honest.

Comment: @Ash I'm sorry I didn't know how else I should call them :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can use them for a **username**.  I tried creating a dummy account using some of the diacritics above and it results in an error message:

[image: invalid account name]

It asks for you to only use a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or underscore (<kbd>_</kbd>).

However, your **profile** name can use them, as I've also tested:

[image: profile name]

Note that your profile name cannot exceed 32 characters, which you can use up quite fast using that "demon text."

Comment: Hmm... I mean you can use some of them:  △ ▽ ⊿ ◤ ◥ ▆ ▇ █ █ ■ ▓   回 □ 〓 ≡ Oh I should mention I dont mean the login Name I mean the displayed Name. Ill edit that!

Comment: @WasteD I've edited my answer as well to address both.  As Kaizer has noted, I'm also not sure how this will display in games.  I suppose the game will have to be able to support those characters, otherwise you might get something like an[][][][][]...

Comment: I like that you have consistency of sanic across multiple platforms, Timmy.

Comment: Just tested it. It works in steam as you said but in BO3 just hashtags :D Pity xD

Answer (score 4):

Although I have not tried to use something as typographically intense as the "demon text", I have used special characters in my **display name**.

[image: Diacritic Display Name]

However, you will not be able to make an account with Diacritic characters. As Timmy Jim explains, you may only use a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or the underscore ( _ ).